# Drush - How to install a specific core base (language)

Tags: drush, i18n-l10n

What is the syntax to download and install the **French** version of core?
https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/fr

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the drush help for `site-install`?

```
/etc/php5/apache2 > drush help site-install
Install Drupal along with modules/themes/configuration using the specified install profile.

Examples:
 drush site-install expert --locale=uk     (Re)install using the expert install profile. Set default language to Ukranian.            
 drush site-install                        Install using the specified DB params.                                                     
 --db-url=mysql://root:pass@localhost:por                                                                                             
 t/dbname                                                                                                                             
 drush site-install                        Install using SQLite (D7+ only).                                                           
 --db-url=sqlite://sites/example.com/file                                                                                             
 s/.ht.sqlite                                                                                                                         
 drush site-install --account-name=joe     Re-install with specified uid1 credentials.                                                
 --account-pass=mom                                                                                                                   
 drush site-install standard               Pass additional arguments to the profile (D7 example shown here - for D6, omit the form    
 install_configure_form.site_default_coun  id).                                                                                       
 try=FR                                                                                                                               
 my_profile_form.my_settings.key=value                                                                                                
 drush site-install                        Disable email notification during install and later. If your server has no smtp, this gets 
 install_configure_form.update_status_mod  rid of an error during install.                                                            
 ule='array(FALSE,FALSE)'

Arguments:
 profile                                   the install profile you wish to run. defaults to 'default' in D6, 'standard' in D7+        
 key=value...                              any additional settings you wish to pass to the profile. Fully supported on D7+, partially 
                                           supported on D6 (single step configure forms only). The key is in the form [form           
                                           name].[parameter name] on D7 or just [parameter name] on D6.

Options:
 --account-mail                            uid1 email. Defaults to admin@example.com                                                  
 --account-name                            uid1 name. Defaults to admin                                                               
 --account-pass                            uid1 pass. Defaults to a randomly generated password. If desired, set a fixed password in  
                                           drushrc.php.                                                                               
 --clean-url                               Defaults to 1                                                                              
 --db-prefix                               An optional table prefix to use for initial install.  Can be a key-value array of          
                                           tables/prefixes in a drushrc file (not the command line).                                  
 --db-su=                            Account to use when creating a new database. Must have Grant permission (mysql only).      
                                           Optional.                                                                                  
 --db-su-pw=                         Password for the "db-su" account. Optional.                                                
 --db-url=      A Drupal 6 style database URL. Only required for initial install - not re-install.         
 --locale=                          A short language code. Sets the default site language. Language files must already be      
                                           present. You may use download command to get them.                                         
 --site-mail                               From: for system mailings. Defaults to admin@example.com                                   
 --site-name                               Defaults to Site-Install                                                                   
 --sites-subdir=           Name of directory under 'sites' which should be created. Only needed when the subdirectory 
                                           does not already exist. Defaults to 'default'

Aliases: si
```

You want to set the `--locale` option, probably to `FR`.